# cell as header with cell2table - Matlab

Tags: matlab

How can I make the 'tHeader' the Header of the table?

```
tHeader = {'objectNum','File','Size'}
RowA = {1,2,3};
RowB = {4,5,6};
tReport = cell2table([tHeader; RowA; RowB])
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Use the `VariableNames` name value pair directly when calling the function:

```
tReport = cell2table([RowA; RowB],'VariableNames',tHeader)
```

Comment: This is probably closer to what the OP wants than my answer is

Answer (score 0):

You can do it as follows:

```
tReport.Properties.VariableNames = tHeader;
```